# Could not find "config/databases/mysql.yml" when make new project rails with mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can someone help me? i got this error when i want to make new project for Ruby on Rails

```
 ronggothelast  ~  belajar-rails  rails new kodooe -d mysql
  create  
  create  README.md
  create  Rakefile
  create  .ruby-version
  create  config.ru
  create  .gitignore
  create  Gemfile
  run  git init from "."
  Initialized empty Git repository in /home/ronggothelast/belajar-rails/kodooe/.git/
  create  package.json
  create  app
  create  app/assets/config/manifest.js
  create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
  create  app/assets/javascripts/cable.js
  create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
  create  app/channels/application_cable/channel.rb
  create  app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb
  create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
  create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
  create  app/jobs/application_job.rb
  create  app/mailers/application_mailer.rb
  create  app/models/application_record.rb
  create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
  create  app/views/layouts/mailer.html.erb
  create  app/views/layouts/mailer.text.erb
  create  app/assets/images/.keep
  create  app/assets/javascripts/channels
  create  app/assets/javascripts/channels/.keep
  create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
  create  app/models/concerns/.keep
  create  bin
  create  bin/bundle
  create  bin/rails
  create  bin/rake
  create  bin/setup
  create  bin/update
  create  bin/yarn
  create  config
  create  config/routes.rb
  create  config/application.rb
  create  config/environment.rb
  create  config/cable.yml
  create  config/puma.rb
  create  config/spring.rb
  create  config/storage.yml
  create  config/environments
  create  config/environments/development.rb
  create  config/environments/production.rb
  create  config/environments/test.rb
  create  config/initializers
  create  config/initializers/application_controller_renderer.rb
  create  config/initializers/assets.rb
  create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
  create  config/initializers/content_security_policy.rb
  create  config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb
  create  config/initializers/cors.rb
  create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
  create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
  create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
  create  config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_5_2.rb
  create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
  create  config/locales
  create  config/locales/en.yml
  create  config/master.key
  append  .gitignore
  create  config/boot.rb
```

> Could not find "config/databases/mysql.yml" in any of your source
>   paths. Your current source paths are: 
>   /home/ronggothelast/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates

Comment: can you try `bundle update` or reinstall rails and then repeat `rails new ...`?

Comment: Okay ,I will try that

Comment: that's  not working for me :(

Answer (score 1):

It seem like you've deleted the mysql.yml.tt from the templates folder using a command to delete all MySQL files on your system.
To fix it:
1) create the mysql.yml.tt file in the directory templates/config/databases/

```
$ touch ~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/config/databases/mysql.yml.tt
```

2) Paste the basic codes from the [original file from rails github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/config/databases/mysql.yml.tt) using vim or opend the file from its source and paste all the codes.

```
$ vim ~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/config/databases/mysql.yml.tt
```

Now you can remake the project using `rails new app-name -d mysql`